# IIS7 automatically redirect to null (in IE)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I'm developing an ASP.NET web site with VB. My web site is work perfectly with Firefox. But,  with IE, it's redirect automatically to *null*.

When I try

```
http://localhost/mysite/Default.aspx
```

IE6/IE7 automatically redirect to

```
http://localhost/mysite/null
```

But, there is no problem with pages inside sub folders. When I try with

```
http://localhost/mysite/forum/
```

It's work perfect. I just can't browse pages in root folder.

What should I do? I'm using IIS7 and .net framework 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Huh... that's strange.  "null" isn't really a normal place for web traffic to get redirected.  Can you think of anywhere in your code/IIS settings that might redirect to a page called "null"  Also strange is the firefox/ie difference.

Does it have something to do with authentication?  IE might have automatic Windows authentication causing your application to behave differently because it thinks you are logged in.  Try turning off Windows Authentication in IIS.

Alternatively, can you debug your code? Does any code execute on your home page before the redirect occurs?

Answer (score 0):

First uncheck the show error frinedly message in the internet explorer in tools->Internet OPtions->Advance then see.

Another thing if you are redirecting with some dynamic link? And that is casuing it to redirect on null.

Check your code. I think that there may be some problem in your code.